# Why I dont get feature props after set it in Draw?

Tags: openlayers

I use this code to set a new props for feature:

```
this.draw.on('drawstart', (e) => {
      e.feature.set('contextmenu', true);
    });
```

After that in context menu event I try to catch feature and filter by this prop:

```
 const feature = this.mapRef.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
      this.mapRef.getEventPixel(evt),
      (feature) => feature
    );
if (feature && feature.get('contextmenu')) {
  // Never call
}
```

Why when I get feature under click it has not contextmenu prop?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting a different feature or no feature?

Comment: Yes, it has not contextmenu in clicked feature

Comment: I got problem is that I am in draw mode. so it returns point geometr where there is not this props. How to prevent click right if draw mode?

Comment: So, I draw some polygons then I need to call right click context where there is button Finish drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is returning the first feature that `forEachFeatureAtPixel` finds.  Yoiu should not return until you find the one you want.

```
 const feature = this.mapRef.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
      this.mapRef.getEventPixel(evt),
      (feature) => {
        if (feature.get('contextmenu') {
          return feature;
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: Yes, it is, but it does not work because at the same time I use new Draw(). Right click in this mode draws a new geometry, how to disable it?

Comment: You could restrict the draw interaction to the left button with `condition: (e) => noModifierKeys(e) && primaryAction(e)`